# Properly publishing/deploying a blazor project to github pages

Tags: c#, web-deployment, github-pages, blazor

I'll start this by saying I'm definitely working a bit above my paygrade here. I'll be doing my best to describe this problem and make it easiest to answer.

I've made a Blazor project in Visual Studio and this is connected to the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/willthamic/ChargeLearning) in the gh-pages branch. After reading Blazor's hosting and deploying guide [here](https://blazor.net/docs/host-and-deploy/index.html), I published the project in Visual Studio and copied the files in the `/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/publish/ChargeLearning/dist` folder to the root of the repository resulting in a repository with this file structure:

```
ChargeLearning
    ChargeLearning
    _content
    _framework
    css
    sample-data
    ChargeLearning.sln
    index.html
```

At this point I think am already neck-deep in bad practice.

Regardless, attempting to load the [index.html](http://willhamic.com/ChargeLearning/) results in 404 errors in the console for most of the files in the html header like bootstrap (as the blazor deploying guide warned).

So I followed the instructions there as best as I could, attempting to implement [this](http://spa-github-pages.rafrex.com/) single page app (SPA) fix for gh-pages linked in the guide.

I added the 404.html file to the ChargeLearning repository now when I load the page it displays just one 404 error, for the `blazor.webassembly.js` file.

I then add the redirect script from the SPA fix to my `willthamic.github.io` [repository](https://github.com/willthamic/willthamic.github.io) which when I open the [direct url](http://willhamic.com/ChargeLearning/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js) to the `blazor.webassembly.js` file seems to redirect properly but github shows my home page and I now realize that it has been severely mangled and now images aren't loading.

I feel like I am doing a lot of things wrong here which makes it difficult to isolate and solve a single problem at once.

If you have specific advice on how to properly deploy this or even small things on how to do what I'm trying to do a little more properly I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read/refer: https://blazor.net/docs/host-and-deploy/index.html#standalone-deployment ?

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari Yes I linked it in my.post and read it multiple.times. Unfortunately it's a but more.complex than my current level of understanding.

Comment: The file structure of blazor demo repository looks quite different are you sure you published your project correctly? https://github.com/blazor-demo/blazor-demo.github.io

Comment: @a.bajorinas That definitely could be the problem but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Comparing the file structures I have all the files they have except for the _bin folder. I am currently using the same directory for the c# project and the published project which results in the extra files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `blazor.webassembly.js` file was stored in a directory beginning with an underscore (_framework), which github's jekyll ignores when deploying the website. After **adding a file named `.nojekyll` to the root of the repository** there was still a 404 error which confused me for a very long time. It then turned out I needed to make a change to another file to cause the website to be rebuilt, finally correcting the issue.

I still feel as though I am doing many things which could be bad practice, but that is for another day. If someone has any advice relating to that I will award the bounty for it.

Comment: @Alexan I believe I fixed the error described in this post but I don't remember this current status of this project.

Comment: If you want to use jekyll and blazor together, you can add ```include:
  - "_framework"
  - "_bin"``` to the `_config.yml` file .  This will tell jekyll to include those files when publishing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the current state of your gh-pages branch I'm guessing you've mixed the files that were in the publish directory with the source files from your solution? If so, you just need to clean the source files out of the gh-pages branch so only the files you copied from the publish directory are present.

Other than that what you have now looks to be correct.

Comment: Do I keep the source files in another branch, like master? Or do I need a separate repository?

Comment: You can keep the source files in the master branch you don’t need a whole separate repo.